# I am trying to call a function within itself, but it does not work for me

Tags: python, function

I am trying to call a function within itself, but it does not work when I run the program. It only works if I type in a value other than 0 in the input. Is there a problem that I am calling the function below the `return` statement?

```
def menu():
    print(‘Choose action: \n 0 - Show menu \n 1 - Classes \n 2 - Add class \n 3 - Add grades \n 4 - Average grade \n 5 - Quit)
    choose_action = int(input('Choose action: '))
    if choose_action == 0:
        menu()
    elif choose_action == 1:
        return classes()
        menu()
    elif choose_action == 2:
        return add_class()
        menu()
    elif choose_action == 3:
        return add_grade()
        menu()
    elif choose_action == 4:
        return average_grade()
        menu()
    elif choose_action == 5:
        return quit_program()


menu()
```

I am calling the `menu()` within itself to make a type of loop.

Comment: you need to read up on functions and `return` so you have a solid understanding of how they work.

Comment: Don't use recursion where a `while` loop will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a problem that I am calling the function below the "return"-statement?

**Yes.**

The return statement terminates the function execution.

Comment: haha i am so stupid. removed "return" and now it works.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

the commands below the return will never be reached and called.